# What kind of component is this?

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/creatingAnInfiniteLoadingList.md

How does one incorporate `MyComponent` into a React app?

Comment: It's a "functional component", see e.g. https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking for. Do you want to know how to use `InfiniteLoader` in your project? What you linked is an example of how you could use it in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the confusing part is that there is a destructuring performed in a function argument. It's basically a react component - function taking props and returning JSX element. However instead of `props` parameter you have `props` destructuring so e.g you don't have to type `props.abc` but just `abc`.

ES 6 feature - more info here: https://simonsmith.io/destructuring-objects-as-function-parameters-in-es6/